# How to access app object from a module in ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I run an Express app like this inside `app.js` file:

```
var app = express();
```

Now I can set some variables like this:

```
app.set('host', 'myhost')
```

I also have `api.js` module and I want to access this host variable from the root `app.js` file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In your `app.js` file:

```
module.exports = app;
```

In your `api.js` file:

```
app = require("./app.js")
host = app.get('host');
```

Comment: My bad, sorry. The require path in api.js is relative, updated code to reflect this.